# Laravel Eloquent. Same relation, different type of return

Tags: php, laravel

I think there is basically no difference between both eloquent relations but work differently.. I can't find what I missed..

There are three model `Concept`, `Attribute`, `Status`. Those models have its own MySQL table `concepts`, `attributes`, `statuses`.

1. Concepts Table

   - id : integer(10) unsigned primary
   - name, description, .. : string(various) nullable
2. Attributes Table

   - id : integer(10) unsigned primary
   - concept_id : integer(10) unsigned foreign on concepts.id
3. Statuses Table

   - id : integer(10) unsigned primary
   - parent_id : integer(10) unsigned foreign on concepts.id

---

To define eloquent relation, I sorted things like below.

- `Concept` has many `Attribute`
- `Concept` has many `Status`

So naturally, I write each relation bidirectionally on each model.

---

Inside model `Concept.php` file..

```
public function attributes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Attribute');
}


public function statuses()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Status');
}
```

---

Inside `Attribute.php` file..

```
public function concept()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Concept');
}
```

---

Inside `Status.php` file..

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Concept');
}
```

---

Problem happens when I use method `$concept->attributes`.

On `Concept.php` file..

```
public function inherit()
{
    // Copy basic concept data. (name, description, etc.)
    $children = $this->replicate();
    $children->name .= ' (Inherited)';
    $children->inherit_parent_id = $this->id;
    $children->inherit_origin_id = $this->inherit_origin_id ?? $this->id;
    $children->save();

    // Inherit Statuses
    foreach( $this->statuses as $status ) {
        $status->inheritTo( $children );
    };

    // Inherit Attributes
    foreach( $this->attributes as $attribute ) {
        $attribute->inheritTo( $children );
    };

    return $children;
}
```

As far as I know, when the first `foreach` was executes, `$this->statuses` returns `Collection` object. However, on the second `foreach` block, `$this->attributes` returns `Concept` object. So I try `$this->attributes()->get()` then it works fine.

Why those two `foreach` block works differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this->attributes` is a inherited property of `Model` class. So it shows these instead the relation.

If you rename your function to refer to the relation, it should work out for you.

Inside model Concept.php file (just an example name)

```
public function rel_attributes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Attribute');
}
```

And you refer to the relation like that:

```
// Inherit Attributes
foreach( $this->rel_attributes as $attribute ) {
    $attribute->inheritTo( $children );
};
```

Comment: I did not know that the Model class had an attributes property. Thanks. I think I can solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Philip's answer. You need to always define relations in eloquent that don't override the default variables.